# icCube - login through proxy - redirect logout to custom loginpage

Tags: authentication, gwt, proxy, iccube

I am using icCube behind my own proxy to redirect login requests to a custom loginpage. At the start of icCube this works fine.

But when I hit the Logout button at the top of the IDE window, I see the following GWT messages:

POST /service.gwt?j_security_check_logout
POST /service.gwt?j_security_check_user

On the first one the icCube server returns an empty response. This seems to be all right.
On the second message the icCube server returns "performFormLogin". This displays the default icCube login window.

Any simple redirect did not work so far, because the service.gwt call expects serverdata.

Can anyone help me what to return to the client to get my own custom loginpage?

Comment: I believe this is not possible in the community edition but should be in the enterprise edition - contact us (icCube) directly.

Answer (score 0):

From icCube 5.1.8 it is possible to configure a servlet filter in icCube.xml to accept a URL for "redirection" on logout. This way, the Javascript code does not open anymore the FORM login but instead open the specified URL.

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>GWT Authentication</filter-name>
    <filter-class>crazydev.iccube.server.authentication.IcCubeGwtAuthenticationServletFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>gwtLogoutRedirectURL</param-name>
        <param-value>http://www.google.com</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
```

Hope that helps.